# How to set metadata options without setting a default value?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

When registering a dependency property how do I set metadata options without setting a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with Object Initializer

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyDependency",
                                typeof(propertyType),
                                typeof(ownerType),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata {
                                    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                                    PropertyChangedCallback = OnPropertyChanged,
                                    ... etc ...
                                });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are four constructors available for PropertyMetadata which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertymetadata.aspx). You can use the third one which doesn't take any default value parameter.

`PropertyMetadata(PropertyChangedCallback)`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeProperty =    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeName", typeof(string), typeof(SomeClass),
                                                                      new PropertyMetadata(SomeChangedCallback),
                                                                      SomeValidateCallback);
```